# Am I doing the correct formulas in this Eigenvalue-with-Multiplicity Question

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have been given the following question:
$$
\dot{X}=\begin{bmatrix}2&-4\\1&-2\end{bmatrix}X + \begin{bmatrix}4\ln t\\\frac{1}{t}\end{bmatrix}
$$
I am told to use the Formula:
$$
\int^t_0 \Psi(t-s)F(s)ds
$$
where $F(t)=\begin{bmatrix}4\ln t\\\frac{1}{t}\end{bmatrix}$
and $\Psi$ is the Normalized Fundamental Matrix.

I have calculated the Eigenvalue(s), $\lambda$, and it is $0$ with multiplicity of 2.
The first Eigenvector is easy to find:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}2&-4\\1&-2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}\\
\begin{bmatrix}2v_1-4v_2=2\\v_1-2v_2=1\end{bmatrix}
$$
This gives me the eigenvector $V_1=\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\end{bmatrix}$, with the corresponding real solution being:
$$
X_1(t)=\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\end{bmatrix} e^{0t}\\=\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$

This is where I am stuck currently. In order to get the Fundamental Matrix, I need a second real solution.
Should I do the following:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}2&-4\\1&-2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}u_1\\u_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\end{bmatrix}\\
$$
in which case the second Eigenvector is $X_2(t)=\begin{bmatrix}-1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$
or is the second real solution $X_2(t)=t\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: The second *generalized* eigenvector is indeed $[-1,-1]$. But since it's not a true eigenvector, the second solution will not be $X_2(t) = [-1,-1]$.

Comment: @Moo: That Formula is where I got the eigenvector $[-1,-1]$ from, however, the values of $v_1$ and $v_2$ are essentially arbitrary